# Load module in nodejs after setting DB data

Tags: node.js

My final goal is to have module.exports to contain some DB value which was loaded during app init

I have tried the following

```
module.exports = (async function() {
const cities = await internalUsage.aggregate(citiesPipeline);
console.log("HandleCities - Cities loaded")
return cities[0].cities;
})();
```

But that gives me a promise

Any idea on how to do that?

** Update **

For now I'm using globals, if anyone has a solution to keep this in the module, I would love to hear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible with only using `module.exports`. Due to the function being `async` the best thing you can get is a `Promise` when using vanilla NodeJS `module.exports`.

This is not that bad if you can `await` for it. `module.exports` works like a factory and only a single Promise will be generated no matter how many times you `require` it.

```
const citiesPromise = require('./XXXXX_XXXXX');

(async function(){
   const cities = await citiesPromise();
   ...
});
```

An alternative solution is to abstract the NodeJS module using `Dependency Injection` (DI) with `asynchronous factory` support. This will allow you to export a `Promise` and get its value as an injection.

Not all NodeJS DI provides this abstraction for `async` values so be careful when selecting DI lib.

You can check [`InversifyJS`](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS) although it encourage using TypeScript it has ES6 example as will https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/basic_js_example.md.